# Separation of a connected open subspace of the plane by a simple closed curve

Tags: algebraic-topology

$A$ is an open connected subspace of $R^2$. $C$ is a simple closed curve contained in $A$. Prove that $C$ separates $A$ into two components.

Comment: Ok, maybe you're expected to _apply_ the Jordan curve Theorem, rather than prove it.

Comment: @quasi, of course. By the way it is easy to see that $A\C$ consists of at least two components.